# Add and delete on foreign key constrained table

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

I have two entities patients and files:
Patients.java:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "personId", nullable = false, unique = true)
private Long personId;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="File_Patient")
private List<Files> files = new ArrayList<>();
```

Files.java:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "personId", nullable = false, unique = true)
private Long personId;

@Column(name = "fileName", nullable = true, unique = false)
private String fileName;
```

I am using a json to add data. Adding is going fine. I add like this:

```
"files": [
        {
            "personId": 3,
            "fileName": "1A"
        },
        {
            "personId": 4,
            "fileName": "2B"
        },
        {
            "personId": 5,
            "fileName": "3C"
        },
        {
            "personId": 6,
            "fileName": "4D"
        }
    ]
```

My update Person method in dao:

```
public Patients updatePerson(String person) {

    Patients result = new Patients();
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(person);
    try {
        Long personId = (Long) obj.get("personId");
        em = factory.createEntityManager();
        String queryStr = "SELECT c FROM Patients c where c.personId = '" + personId + "'";
        TypedQuery<Patients> query = em.createQuery(queryStr, Patients.class);
        result = query.getSingleResult();
        List<Files> f = result.getFiles();

        if (obj.get("files") != null) {
                boolean flag;
                JSONArray files = (JSONArray) obj.get("files");
                List<Files> fi = new ArrayList<>();
                Files file = new Files();
                for (int i = 0 ; i < files.size() ; i ++) {
                    log.info(files.get(i).toString());
                    file.setFileName(files.get(i).toString());
                    fi.add(file);                       
                }
                result.setFiles(fi);
        }

        em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.merge(result);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        log.error("Exception caught :: " + e);
        em.getTransaction().rollback();
    }
    em.close();
    return result;
}
```

But the scenario is:
While updating, I will add more files or not. The code needs to check on that and delete files which are not in update and add the new files.
Now, I am not able to delete using the usual em.remove().

And while adding it gives this error :
Exception caught :: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: File_patient is not mapped [SELECT f FROM File_patient f where f.files_personid = '3']

Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: Why do you use a File_Patient join table? Just add @JoinColumn to point on the personId on the files table.

Comment: @simas_ch I am fairly new to this. I will try this now.

Comment: Then you should probably first read a book or go through the excellent Hibernate Doc http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html

Comment: @simas_ch I am getting this error now : "ERROR: insert or update on table "files" violates foreign key constraint "fk_exgyjxr0t4yrh57otkyyqn8wa"
  Detail: Key (personid)=(5) is not present in table "patients"."

Comment: This exactly says what happened. Does the Patient with id 5 exist in the DB?

Comment: No it doesn't. Thats why I am confused. The files table is empty

Comment: Can you provide some code how you process the Patient and File?

Comment: @simas_ch I have added the code to updatePerson method in which I would like to add the files to the person.

Comment: You are doing manual transaction management. Where is your app running?

Comment: On tomcat.. local machine @simas_ch

Comment: and you don't use anything like spring framework?